# Xamarin UI test fail to identify System dialog(s) of iOS App

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to automate our iOS app using xamarin UI test. To access the app, user has to give his/her TouchID. But both Xamarin Test recorder and Repl() failed to identify the Touch ID system dialog (Please see attached screenshot).

This dialog is not developed by our developers and it is a system dialog.

How do I perform the action(s) which associated with this Touch ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

System dialogs is not something you can query with calabash or Xamarin.UITest, which is super annoying.

You would need to use a backdoor to simulate a success or fail state for this. You can read more about these here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/

Basically you define a method in your AppDelegate:

```
[Export("touchIdBackdoor:")] // notice the colon at the end of the method name
public NSString TouchIdBackdoor(NSString value)
{
    if (value == "true")
    {
        //simulate ok finger press
    }
    else
    {
        //simulate failed finger
    }
}
```

Then in your test, when you expect the touch id to appear, you invoke the backdoor:

```
app.Invoke("touchIdBackdoor:", "true");
```

To dismiss the touch id and set whatever you need to continue.